# Explain what this is for me?

Tags: python, string

So, I've seen this type thing on several occasions, but I've never been able to find out anything about it. Can someone please explain what these "r' foo(*)'" things are and link me to the python docs for them? I think they have to do with finding key words in strings. Am I right?

```
(r'why (.*) i (.*)\?', 
( "You%1%2?", 
"Perhaps you only think you%1%2")), 

(r'why (.*) you(.*)\?', 
( "Why%1 you%2?", 
"%2 I%1", 
"Are you sure I%2?")), 

(r'why (.*)\?', 
( "I cannot tell you why%1.", 
"Why do you think %1?" )),
```

This particular segment of code is from the nltk.chat.zen module.

Comment: How about a reasonable subject line?

Comment: @Blackmoon Sorry, I'm a little tired and frustrated right now.
I'll be sure to be more clear next time though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those appear to be [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). Regular expressions let you search for patterns in strings in a fairly powerful and sophisticated way. They can be a bit cryptic though. These appear to be the basis of some kind of primitive chatterbot.

```
>>> import re
>>> regex, phrases = (r'why (.*) i (.*)\?', 
... ( "You %s %s?", 
... "Perhaps you only think you %s %s"))
>>> phrase1, phrase2 = phrases
>>> groups = re.search(regex, 'why am i dumb?')
>>> phrase1 % (groups.group(1), groups.group(2))
'You am dumb?'
>>> phrase2 % (groups.group(1), groups.group(2))
'Perhaps you only think you am dumb'
```

Ah, and perhaps you were specifically wondering what `r'blahblah'` means. Well, as others have explained, the `r` just makes it a raw string -- Python doesn't do certain kinds of processing on it, which makes REs easier to read.

---

Here's something closer to what I think the original intent was for these strings. They don't seem to be using standard Python group substitution syntax, so I assume they must be using a custom substitution function for this -- perhaps one sophisticated enough to handle converting the verb form! You can see the basic idea [here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub).

```
>>> import re
>>> regex, phrases = (r'why (.*) i (.*)\?',
... ( r'You \g<1> \g<2>?',
...   r'Perhaps you only think you \g<1> \g<2>.'))
>>> phrase1, phrase2 = phrases
>>> re.sub(regex, phrase1, 'why am i dumb?')
'You am dumb?'
>>> re.sub(regex, phrase2, 'why am i dumb?')
'Perhaps you only think you am dumb.'
```

Comment: How do I use them to search strings for patterns?

Comment: @xBlink: You use the `re` module. http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: @xBlink another good python regex doc: [howto](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex)

Answer (score 2):

In Python, `r'something'` or `r"something"` are [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals). The difference between normal strings and raw strings is that in the latter backslash characters (`\`) don't need to be escaped.

In the code you give the raw strings appear to be used to specify [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html), which is a common use case for raw strings.

Regular expressions are used to search for patterns or match patterns. There is a good tutorial [here](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html).

Answer (score 0):

As noted by aix, `r` signifies it is a raw string. And as noted by the others, the strings in question are regular expressions. Raw strings are useful to represent regular expressions, since they do not need to be escaped (for instance, when you write `\\` to get a single "\" in your output, you have escaped the backslash). Backslashes are very frequent in regular expressions, so not having to duplicate them improves clarity.